Linux Distro with MacOS-like Smooth (kinetic) Touchpad Scrolling
I'm a relatively-new Linux user (Ubuntu 22.04) and something has recently started to bug me immensely - the lack of kinetic scrolling in many apps.
After doing some digging, it seems that kinetic scrolling (at least in Ubuntu) must be implemented at the level of the applications. Contrast this with say, MacOS, which features kinetic scrolling as part of the operating system itself.
That said - are there any distros that come "pre-packaged", as it were, with kinetic scrolling?
EDIT:
Hell, I'll even lower the bar - if anyone knows of a distro that allows me to simply modify something so that I use kinetic scrolling regardless of the app I'd be eternally in your debt.

the good news is that this won't be a property of a specific distro; so if it can be done on any Linux distro, it'll work on your Ubuntu most likely.

I'm not sure what you mean with "kinetic scrolling", however. Could you refer me to an explanation of what it is?

More information can be found here: https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/uzt34n/whats_the_status_of_inertial_scrolling/

I'm sorry, I can't find a clear definition of kinetic scrolling in a reddit thread. I'm also not willing to guess what reddit users that tell each other they don't understand each other mean with kinetic scrolling. I'm afraid you'll have to explain it to me :(
